# TSQL Patindex single numeric value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like your help in solving the following issue using the Patindex function i cannot retrieve or extract the single numeric value as an example in the the values below i would like retrieve the Value 2, but in my result set the value 22 also appears or it is completely omitted.

I need to extract the Single numeric value 2 and not 22

"2 8 7"

"2 8"

"2"

"22"

"3 2 8"

I have tried the following
Patindex('%[2]% [^0-9] [^1] [^3] [^4] [^5] [^6] [^7] [^8] [^9]' ,Replace(Replace(Marketing_Special_Attributes, '"',''),'^',' ')) as Col3,

Patindex('[2]' ,Replace(Replace(Marketing_Special_Attributes, '"',''),'^',' ')) as Col4,

Patindex('%[2][^0-9]%',Replace(Marketing_Special_Attributes,'^',' ')),

All help is appreciated

Comment: please post the output you want

Answer (score 1):

You can identify a single digit with:

```
where ' ' + col + ' ' like '% [0-9] %'
```

Hence, you can do the something similar to find a pattern:

```
select substr(col, patindex('% [0-9] %', ' ' + col + ' '), 1)
```

(Because of the spaces, the `patindex()` value is off-by-1 relative to the original string.)

However, you seem to be storing lists of numbers as a string -- and that is a bad idea.  Lists should be stored in tables, with one row per entity and entity item.